# How to step into the MPI functions?

Tags: debugging, mpi, openmpi, mpich

Salute! Is it possible to debug MPI program like step into one of the library function (e.g. `MPI_Send()`) and see what happens in it? I already tried to do that with GDB and MS Visual Studio debugger but it was unsuccessful.

Comment: Only if the MPI library was compiled with debug information and the source code is available.